# Why the LeNet5 uses 32×32 image as input?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I know that the handwritten digit images in the mnist dataset are 28×28，but why the input in LeNet5 is 32×32?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is answered in the [original paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf): 
The convolution step always takes a smaller input than the feature maps of the previous layer (and this holds true for the 1st layer - the input - as well):

> Layer C1 is a convolutional layer with 6 feature maps.
>   Each unit in each feature map is connected to a 5x5 neighborhood in the input. The size of the feature maps is 28x28
>   which prevents connection from the input from falling off
>   the boundary.

This means that using a 5x5 neighborhood on a 32x32 input, you'll get 6 features maps of size 28x28 because there's pixels you won't use at the image boundary (you will always have a remainder with these numbers).

Of course they could have an exception for the first layer. The reason they're still using 32x32 images is:

> The input is a 32x32 pixel image. This is significantly larger
>   than the largest character in the database (at most 20x20
>   pixels centered in a 28x28 field). The reason is that it is
>   desirable that potential distinctive features such as stroke
>   end-points or corner can appear in the center of the receptive field of the highest-level feature detectors.

Comment: i think the OP is asking why MNIST is a 28x28 dataset but the paper use 32x32 as input. for sure the first conv layer reduce it from 32x32 to 28x28, but with 28x28 input, it will reduce to 24x24 after first conv layer

Comment: The last quote from the paper answers OP's question, which you correctly repeated, so I'm not sure what you are trying to say.